# How to make sub menu in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Hello i wanted to make like following image so how can i do that in WordPress

[image: Wanted to make navigation like this]

Thanks

Vishal

Comment: Are you trying to connect the 'Home, About, Pages, Portfolio' menu with the items in the dark box, or are you just trying to replicate the contents of the dark box?

Answer (score 1):

Vishal,

What you're going to need to do is create four widget areas first.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgetizing_Themes

With those four widget areas you'll need to call them in the file you are using for your footer, typically footer.php.

Then with those four widget areas created you can add all sorts of widgets in those areas. To duplicate the image above you'll want to use the following widgets:a custom menu widget in the first widget area, a category widget for the second widget area, a recent posts widget for the third widget area, and a popular posts widget that would probably require a plugin.

Here is some information on the widgets wordpress offers: http://en.support.wordpress.com/widgets/

Finally, all you'll need is some styling and you should be good to go.

Comment: sir i need widget area in menu not in footer and image is of menu with hover effect not footer For example search for limitless theme on themeforset.com it has this type of menu i want to do like that

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this with Ubermenu, a premium WordPress plugin http://wpmegamenu.com/